# In ggplot2 (R Studio), is there a way to extend the regression lines to the end of the plot rather than the last data point

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

I am a relative novice to R & ggplot. I am trying to plot an interaction. When I plot the interaction using SPSS - the regression lines go from the y-axis all the way to the opposite edge of the plot:

[image]

However, when I use ggplot, the regression lines only go as far as the first and last data point which makes the graph look strange

[image]

Is there any way to remedy this and make my ggplot look more like the SPSS plot?

Here is the code I am using

```
No5Plot <- ggplot(data=pccdata, aes(x= factor2, y = pcc, color = Factor.1)) +
  geom_point(size=1.2) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
  labs(x = "Factor 2", y = "Posterior Cingulate Cortex \n Gyrification")
No5Plot + scale_color_manual(values = c("#CC79A7", "#009E73", "#0072B2")) + 
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20), axis.text = element_text(size=15))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  To help us to help you would you mind sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. To share your data, you could type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first ten rows of data.

Comment: Try with `geom_smooth(..., fullrange=TRUE`). See [ggplot2: Extend stat_smooth regression line to entire x-range of plot area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526124/ggplot2-extend-stat-smooth-regression-line-to-entire-x-range-of-plot-area)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geom_smooth` has a `fullrange` option, which has a default value of `FALSE`:

> Should the fit span the full range of the plot, or just the data?

Thus, you can use:

```
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE)
```